# How to make a download attribute for an mp3 file?

Tags: html, css, download, attributes, mp3

I have been trying to make a download link for a mp3 file and I can't seem to have been doing anything. The mp3 file is in the right place but when I click on it, it just opens in a new tab playing the audio file. The file position is like this:

```
<a href="forsongstab/tracks/Villagers of Ioannina City - Age of Aquarius - 01 Welcome.mp3" download="Villagers of Ioannina City - Age of Aquarius - 01 Welcome"><img class="dli" src="../images/downloadicon.jpeg">01. Welcome</a>
```

If anyone can find a way to fix please let me know. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A solution using javascript only:**

```js
function downloadBlob(blob, filename) {
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  a.download = filename;
  a.href = blob;
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.click();
  a.remove();
}

function downloadResource(url) {
  filename = url.split('\\').pop().split('/').pop();
  fetch(url, {
      mode: 'no-cors'
    })
    .then(response => response.blob())
    .then(blob => {
      let blobUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      downloadBlob(blobUrl, filename);
    })
    .catch(e => console.error(e));
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:downloadResource('https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3')">01. Welcome</a>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I have been trying to find a solution for two weeks now and this is the simplest and closest one that I have found. Thank you!

Comment: Hello, I have a question once again. That link works fine but do you know a way on how I can add a location from my folder. I tried it like this 

```
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:downWloadResource('fontsongtab/tracks/Villages of Ioannina City - Age of Aquarius - 01 elcome.mp3')">01. Welcome</a>
```

If you could help me once again I would be very thankful. Thank you.

Comment: Good code! was able to implement this on Wix mp3 download.

Comment: for some reason the file that is downloaded is 0KB....

Comment: If anyone is trying this solution and it results in Zero Bytes files being downloaded, then it's due to mode -> mode: 'no-cors', most of free sample audio available don't have proper cors header set, check here for cors available web audio - https://mikehelland.github.io/omg-sounds/

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add this HTTP header to your response to make the browser force a download:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=your_filename.mp3
```

For example, if you're using PHP on the server side, you can create a script that sends the above header followed by the actual file contents:

```
$path = $_GET['path'];
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($path));
readfile($path);
```

If you call this script download.php, then linking to download.php?path=/path/to/your/file.mp3 will make the browser pop-up a download dialog for file.mp3.

Comment: Thank you for your response but I am really new to html and css so I can't really understand all that. Could you please explain it to me better and maybe tell me what I can do exactly to fix my problem? It would really help me. Thank you.

Comment: It would be far better to just configure the web server, in this case.  No need for PHP if it's not already in use.

Comment: This script is very dangerous. With its help, you can get non-interpreted php scripts or other server files. For example:
download.php?path=/etc/shadow

Answer (score 0):

.then(response => response.blob()) lack return

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.